# How to pass data from django to bootstrap modal?

Tags: ajax, django-models, django-templates, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to pass django data to bootstrap modal.

Now I'm using `django-bootstrap-modal-forms` pypi package.

I've seen this [documents](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/) and I tried to it, but it isn't work.

I only need to perform the reading function.

How should I set it up to pass the data for that modal?

The parts that float modal components and lists are inside the same html file.

No Item was printed when the modal component was written as follows.

```html
{% if item %}
 {{item}}
{% else %}
  No Item
{% endif %}
```

- views.py

```py
from bootstrap_modal_forms.generic import BSModalReadView

...

def index(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'items': items,
        'search_items': items
    })

...

class DetailLectureReadView(BSModalReadView):
    model = Item


class DetailTaskReadView(BSModalReadView):
    model = Item
```

- urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp.home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('search/', views.serarch, name="search"),
    path('register/<int:id>', views.register, name="register"),
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.delete, name="delete"),
    path('detail-lecture/<int:id>',
         views.DetailLectureReadView.as_view(), name="detail_lecture"),
    path('detail-task/<int:id>',
         views.DetailTaskReadView.as_view(), name="detail_task")
]
```

- models.py

```py
from django.db import models


class Item(models.Model):
    lecture_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    lecture = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    professor = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    start_time = models.IntegerField()
    end_time = models.IntegerField()
    day_of_week = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    is_register = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lecture
```

- index.html (lecture list)

```html
{% if search_items %}
        {% for item in search_items %}
        <ul class="list-lecture">
            <li class="card-lecture" >
                <a class="lecture-title detail_lecture" 
                   href="#modal-lecture-info" 
                   data-toggle="modal" 
                   data-target="modal-lecture-info" 
                   data-id="{% url 'detail_lecture' item.id %}">
                {{ item.lecture }}
                </a>
                <h6 class="lecture-time">
                    <i class="material-icons ic-lecture-info">access_time</i>
                    <span>
                    {{ item.start_time|stringformat:"02d" }} - {{ item.end_time|stringformat:"02d" }} | 
                    {% if item.day_of_week|length == 2 %}
                    ({{ item.day_of_week.0 }}), ({{item.day_of_week.1}})
                    {% else %}
                    ({{ item.day_of_week.0 }})
                    {% endif %}
                    </span>
                </h6>
                <ul class="list-lecture-info">
                    <li>Code : {{ item.lecture_code }}</li>
                    <li>Professor : {{ item.professor }}</li>
                    <li>Location : {{ item.location }}</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        No result
        {% endif %}
```

- index.html (modal)

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-lecture-info" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="modal" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3 class="lecture-title">{{ item.lecture }}</h3>
                <ul class="lecture-info">
                    <li class="lecture-time">
                        <i class="material-icons ic-lecture-info">access_alarm</i>
                        <span>Lecture Time : {{ item.start_time|stringformat:"02d" }} - {{ item.end_time|stringformat:"02d" }} | 
                        {% if item.day_of_week|length == 2 %}
                        ({{ item.day_of_week.0 }}), ({{ item.day_of_week.1 }})
                        {% else %}
                        ({{ item.day_of_week.0 }})
                        {% endif %}
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="lecture-code">
                        <i class="material-icons ic-lecture-info">code</i>
                        <span>code : {{ item.code }}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="lecture-code">
                        <i class="material-icons ic-lecture-info">school</i>
                        <span>professor : {{ item.professor }}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="lecture-code">
                        <i class="material-icons ic-lecture-info">business</i>
                        <span>location : {{ item.location }}</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="lecture-description">
                    <p class="txt-description">this is description
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='{% url 'register' 2 %}'">Lecture Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- script.js

```js
$(".card-lecture").click(function() {
    $("#modal-lecture-info").modal("show");
    $(".detail_lecture").each(function() {
        $(this).modalForm({
            formURL: $(this).data("id")
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using jQuery

Comment: it is important if you share the solution you found.